# How do I make my page look good in Google Instant Previews?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, google-instant-previews

When you view a page from my site in [Google Instant Previews](http://www.google.com/landing/instantpreviews/), you see an AJAX error message (caused by some AJAX that fires on document ready):

[image]

I assume the way to fix this is to make my javascript compatible with whatever javascript engine Google's "browser" uses (like one might design for IE6).

So: what javascript does Google Instant Previews understand?

Comment: Any information on what scripts fire onload? Seems obvious that they use a variant of Chromium and V8.

Comment: But my site works fine in Chrome..

Comment: trying to find an example, but I chuckled earlier today when a Google result showed in Instant Preview as "you need to have Javascript enabled to view this site"

Comment: How many ms does it take for the error to occur?

Comment: @JoshN: I don't know; there's some *synchronous* AJAX that runs on document ready to set up the page (which is what's failing, I suppose)

Comment: I suppose a convoluted way around this is to modify your server error reporting to tell you when the error occurs, then just set a longer timeout for your AJAX call if the referrer is /.*google.com.*/.

Comment: For anyone trying to fix this now, please remember that Instant Previews were discontinued 5 months ago due to low usage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Previews are generated in one of two ways:

- Via normal Googlebot crawls
- On the fly using the user-agent `Mozilla/5.0 (en-us) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Web Preview) Version/3.1 Safari/525.13`

If the content has been crawled recently, it's likely to reuse the normal crawled content. If not, then it'll try to generate it on the fly. Internally, it uses a similar Safari/Webkit-based browser, so that's what you'd probably want to use to check your pages. I believe there's a way to modify the user-agent that Safari uses, which would be one way to do a more specific check.

If for some reason the AJAX content can't be fetched (say it's disallowed by robots.txt or the server actively blocks Googlebot from accessing it), then the site should fail gracefully (as it should when users run into the same problem). Don't show an error popup -- just log it internally and fall back to some default content.

One way to double-check if it works after you have made changes to your site's template is to do a site:-query to find similar, obscure pages, and to check their preview images; if nobody else has checked the preview images, it will be rendered on the fly so you will see the results right away. Once you're happy with how it renders, it will take a bit of time to catch up and re-render the existing pages; it doesn't update with the same frequency as cached pages or normal snippets do.

Answer (score 12):

Here is [Google's description](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/instant-previews-under-hood.html) of the preview tool for users. Here is there [Developer FAQs](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-instant-previews#02).

Comment: Now that would be the link I'm interested in!

Comment: Good link, but this doesn't describe how the screenshots are created

Comment: @Horace I added another link that actually does give the down and dirty.

Answer (score 5):

It seems odd that your page tells the visitor that there was a JavaScript error in the first place. As a web user, I would be annoyed to get a pop-up because the AJAX failed. My suggestion would be to remove that pop-up and have your AJAX retry if there was an error.

Comment: Maybe the AJAX should retry, but *eventually* I have to stop retrying and let it fail, and when I do I have to notify the user because refreshing the page might fix the problem (Google Docs takes the same approach). Anyway, regardless of whether there's an error message, the page that Google Preview sees is different from the page my users see, and I want to know how to minimize this difference

Comment: +1 for Timmy because he's right(ish) in my opinion although you also have a great point, Horace. Even if you tell the users that there was an error with the XHR, this shouldn't happen in an intrusive way, for example by covering content. 
The difference between GDocs and the picture from your post, Horace is that GDocs presents the error message in a rather small box in an empty area of the page and thus it doesn't affect how I am reading the content on that particualr page. I don't have to click X or drag the error message to get back reading. It's just slightly better user experience :)