# Google instant preview api

Tags: google-search, google-instant-previews

Is there a way to leverage Google's Instant Preview? We have a site that displays results from Google and now my company would like to integrate Instant Previews. When I look at the url generated that gets the preview images, it looks to be the image data in json format.

Comment: Just some more info: The url where the images are requested is for example : http://clients1.google.com/webpagethumbnail?c=11&r=2&f=2&s=300:585&query=stuff&hl=en&gl=us&d=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stuff.co.nz%2F&b=1&j=google.vs.r&a=AIYkKU-1v_x3fQhJdcN8GaIm6LVtSfla1Q
So it might be related to the keyword "webpagethumbnail"

Comment: This overlaps an awful lot with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151815/how-do-i-make-my-page-look-good-in-google-instant-previews/4201497#4201497

Answer (score 0):

[for more about Google instant preview api](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feed-api-now-with-instant.html)

Note: This blog post deals with Instant for Google Feed Api, not the general Google Instant.